# React Player unable to play TikTok videos?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-player

I have a code which is expecting for a user's video link and/or embedded video, in order to pass on to a React Player component.

With youtube/vimeo/dailymotion... the flow is working just fine, but when it comes to TikTok videos, I am getting a greyed out player, which's not showing time duration of the video and is unable to play.

I'm receiving the following error:

```
Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'error', target: video, currentTarget: video, eventPhase: 2, …}isTrusted: truebubbles: falsecancelBubble: falsecancelable: truecomposed: falsecurrentTarget: nulldefaultPrevented: falseeventPhase: 0returnValue: truesrcElement: videotarget: videotimeStamp: 22923.80000000447type: "error"[[Prototype]]: Event 'error
```

Any ideas as for how to solve this issue?